# Windows Phone 8.1 one line equivalent for getPixels & createBitmap from Android?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm porting over some code from an Android app using the [android-jhlabs library](https://code.google.com/p/android-jhlabs/) to a Windows Phone 8.1 runtime app.

The code is quite simple and basically looks like the following (in Java):

```
PointillizeFilter filter = new PointillizeFilter();
filter.setEdgeColor(Color.BLACK);
filter.setScale(10f);
filter.setRandomness(0.1f);
filter.setAmount(0.1f);
filter.setFuzziness(0.1f);
filter.setTurbulence(10f);
filter.setGridType(PointillizeFilter.SQUARE);
int[] src = AndroidUtils.bitmapToIntArray(artWork);
src = filter.filter(src, width, height);
Bitmap destImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
```

In Java:

```
public static int[] bitmapToIntArray(Bitmap bitmap){
    final int bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    final int bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

    int[] colors = new int[bitmapWidth *  bitmapHeight];
    bitmap.getPixels(colors, 0, bitmapWidth, 0, 0, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight);

    return colors;
}
```

I've converted this function to C#, with a slight problem:

```
 public static int[] bitmapToIntArray(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
    {
        int bitmapWidth = bitmapImage.PixelWidth;
        int bitmapHeight = bitmapImage.PixelHeight;

        int[] colors = new int[bitmapWidth * bitmapHeight];

         // how to convert line below?
        //bitmap.getPixels(colors, 0, bitmapWidth, 0, 0, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight);

        return colors;
    }
```

Looking through the documentation, I see a lot of different classes for bitmaps: WriteableBitmap, BitmapImage, BitmapEncoder and BitmapDecoder. I did not find a getPixel class for Windows Phone 8.1, but there is one for Windows Store apps. Even there, it's only for getting one pixel.

Same goes the createBitmap() command. I couldn't find any equivalent.

My question is, is there a one line equivalent for the getPixels() and createBitmap() command for Windows Phone 8.1? Would it be best to use the [BitmapDecoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709939.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

You must use BitmapDecoder:

```
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);

var pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
var pixels = pixelData.DetachPixelData();

var width = decoder.OrientedPixelWidth;
var height = decoder.OrientedPixelHeight;

for (var i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        byte r = pixels[(i * height + j) * 4 + 0]; //red
        byte g = pixels[(i * height + j) * 4 + 1]; //green
        byte b = pixels[(i * height + j) * 4 + 2]; //blue (rgba)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it, but the code doesn't run after the first line no matter how I play around with it. I put it into the following function call:
`public static async Task<int[]> bitmapToIntArray(Image bitmapImage)`
and it returns an int[] array. I do replace 'fileName' with the name of the jpg image I'm trying to open.

I call this function in my main code using this line of code: 
`int[] src = PixelUtils.bitmapToIntArray(userImage).Result;`

Any further suggestions on what I can try?

Comment: Follow up question linked in case any other users encounter a similar problem in the future: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055689/windows-phone-8-1-bitmapdecoder-async-await-not-stepping-through-the-entire-func)

Comment: LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName) == file from local folder of application, if you wont get file from sdcard or phone use filePicker